# Session class not found when loading third party libararies

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to use a [third party library](https://github.com/gnello/php-openfire-restapi) for openfire in my Codeigniter Application.

So I have put the libarary in third party folder, and have created an index.php file where I configure my Library.

Then I created a class file in library folder called index.php and I call the third party library like this:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Open extends MY_Controller
{


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}



public function index()
{
    require_once APPPATH.'third_party/openfire/index.php';
}
```

}

Finally created a controller called user.php and tried to load this libaray using :

```
$this->load->library('Open');
```

But on screen this shows me error:

> Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Its an unexpected error! what can be the possible reasons for this ? If i stop load this library everything works fine.

And I have already loaded Session in autload.php

Comment: Try to load `$this->load->library('session');` in `__construct()`

Comment: @Loading.. i tried still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class Open extends MY_Controller

Try not extending the MY_Controller

Comment: I also tried extending it to CI_Controller but it did not work

Comment: Do not extend any class